# How to format and return <style jsx> string from a function in React or Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to find a way to "organize" react component like vue, where it's bundled together with different section for HTML, JS and CSS.

For example

```
export default function HeaderExample() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <style jsx>{`
        h1 {
          color: yellow;
        }
      `}
      </style>
    </>
  )
}
```

I want to convert to:

```
export default function HeaderExample() {
  const compStyle = getStyle();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <style jsx>{compStyle}
      </style>
    </>
  )
}

function getStyle() {
  return `
        h1 {
          color: yellow;
        }
      `
}
```

It does work, but writing it is pretty hard because there is no syntax highlight or anything.

Is that a good convention in general?

And is there a way to enable syntax highlight / formatting help for this type of thing? And should it also work with SCSS or PostCSS?

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of [styled-jsx](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=blanu.vscode-styled-jsx) for Visual Studio Code.  It color coordinates my styled jsx just like my regular css files.  It does not have the formatter built in however.

If you want something more like Vue, try [React-Styles-Hook](https://github.com/gadingnst/react-styles-hook).
Here is their standard example

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useStyles } from 'react-styles-hook'

const App = () => (
    <div style={styles.container}>
        <h1 style={styles.title}>Hello React </h1>
    </div>
)

const styles = useStyles({
    container: {
        height: 100,
        width: '100%',
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
})

export default App
```

Intellisense is built in and your default formatter should work.

The first suggestion I shared is just an extension for VS Code.  This second one is a package you have to install in your app.  I hope this helps.